# Move First Variable To Second Variable When New Input Received

Tags: javascript, variables, input, var

**UPDATE** Var A should be receiving a new value however var b should only retain var a's previous value. If var a is 7 then it is later updated to 9 then var b should show the older instance of 7 while var a displays 9. Both would have to be able to save to local storage. Currently only var a is saving to local storage.

I'm working in Javascript and I want to move variable data into another variable when a user inputs form data.

var a = 0;
var b = 0;

When the user first inputs data var a receives a value and saves it to local storage (this works fine).

If the user accesses this form again (var a now has a value) I want it to move to var b and then have the newly entered data save to var a.

This process would be repeated. var b will always be replaced by var a when the user accesses the form again. This is so I can show a past instance vs the latest instance. Any ideas?

```
<form id="exercise-count"> <input id="form1" type="number" name="userinput"></form>

var a = documentGetElementById("userinput").value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just always assign the value of `a` to `b`?

```
// Somewhere:
var a, b;

// Somewhere else:
b = a;
a = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
```

Comment: No this is just assigning b to a. Var a should be receiving new values and var b should be receiving the previous value a had before the new value.

Comment: That's *exactly* what this code is doing: assign `a`'s current (previous) value to `b`. Assign the new input value to `a`. It does **not** assign `b` to `a`.

Comment: Hmm I see what you're saying...I played with the fiddle a bit more but it's saving only one value to local storage which seems to be the value of what is inside of the form. It isn't storing the previous value. So if you were to access the page again it isn't showing the latest value (var a) and the previous value (var b). If I'm missing something, I have only been coding in JS since December and still have a lot to learn.

Comment: Well, if you also want to store `b` in local storage, you have to do that explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the request in the question. Trying to use this currently with local storage is giving var b the same value as var a. So when I update var a to 15, var b is saving as 15

Comment: Then you are passing the wrong value. Just run `localStorage.setItem('a', a); localStorage.setItem('b', b);` after you updated `a`. Without seeing your actual code, I can only guess what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Yep! You're absolutely right I tweaked it and this works perfectly. I am very grateful for your guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if `var a` already has a value in the localStorage

```
if(localStorage.getItem("a") == undefined) {
    //save a
} else {
    //save a to b
    //save a
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will answer your question:

```
var input = document.getElementById('form1');
var a = localStorage.getItem('userinput');
var b = a;

input.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyUp);

function onKeyUp(event) {
  a = this.value;
  localStorage.setItem('userinput', a);
}
```

**JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/s0dk5j6w/4/**

Comment: The problem is var b is always updating with a. Var A should be receiving a new value however var b should only retain var a's previous value. If var a is 7 then it is later updated to 9 then var b should show the older instance of 7 while var a displays 9.